# Product/market fit - desirability testing

Tags: user-research

The scenario: Freshening up a consumer app design to see if users feel like it's viscerally the right fit for them. We'd also like to see how the design is performing among competitors in this sense.

Workflows, jobs-to-be-done, and tasks are not being tested. This is strictly to test look and feel, to answer questions like, "I'm Gen Z, is this app for me, or for older people?"

[Standard desirability studies](https://www.xdstrategy.com/desirability-studies/) aside - is there a problem with having participants who fit the target shopper evaluate and rank 6 designs in order from "feels most like me" to "feels least like me", to see how those map across demographic traits? Or would that produce results that are too broad or random to be useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the proposed method of having participants who fit the target shopper evaluate and rank 6 designs in order from "feels most like me" to "feels least like me," this can be a useful exercise to gain insights into how the different design options are perceived by the target audience. However, it is important to keep in mind that the results may be limited in their usefulness.

For example, the results may only provide a high-level understanding of which designs are preferred by different demographic groups, but they may not provide a deep understanding of why certain designs are preferred over others. Additionally, the results may not necessarily translate to actual usage or adoption of the app.

To address these limitations, it may be helpful to complement the "feels most like me" exercise with additional qualitative research, such as user interviews or focus groups, to gain more in-depth insights into users' perceptions and preferences. This can help your friend understand why certain designs are more appealing to certain demographics and what specific aspects of the design resonate with users.

If addition of that, I would try to do the same test with obvious people that are not the target for the reason that you would be surprise by the results (sometimes) and could have some new opportunities.

I'm sure there is other valid approach, but I hope this small input of mine helps you :)